# Equivalent in DataFrame.rolling of ngroups from DataFrame.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there an equivalent of ngroups from DataFrame.groupby in DataFrame.rolling?

If the window is numeric I get it that it is

```
nwindows = len(DataFrame)-min_periods+1
```

but what happens when the window is some freq? Is it lazy-evaluated or is there any variable which contains the number of windows that are going to be used? Some kind of property of the Rolling object.

EDIT: Added example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 10
dates = pd.pandas.date_range(start="2017-01-01", periods=N, freq="10s").values
vals = np.random.rand(N)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(dates, vals)), columns=['date', 'rnd'])
roll = df.rolling(window='1min', min_periods=2, on='date')
roll.mean()
```

Rephrasing my question: Can I know beforehand how many times `mean()` is going to be called?

Comment: This isn't helping. We need to know your use case and what you are trying to do. Some data and output would help. Answering abstract questions is for the pandas developers on GitHub.

Comment: I've added an example although I don't think it adds that much to the question.